# Magento 1.9 categories not loading after import

Tags: performance, magento, import, loading, magento-1.9

I'm currently stuck at my magento shop and I can't find a solution. I want to import almost 600.000 products. The process of it is really slow. The more product are in the system, the slower the import of new products works. I also can't open some category pages. Its simply not loading.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your indexes are set to auto-update you should switch them to manual mode before importing. this is a common reason for decreasing performance (and db locks)

```
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($collection as $process) {
  $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)->save();
}
```

after import you could switch back to

```
  $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)->save();
```

Comment: provide some more context about how you import your products

Comment: I was using this tutorial to import the data: http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/

Comment: that is ok, but what is your datasource? anyway using the product model  Mage::getModel('catalog/product') is one of the most inefficient ways to save data in magento)). If you want to implement it in php in context of magento use Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product. I will add another answer with a github repo

Answer (score 0):

You should look into https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport

This one is based on Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product and is therefore much faster, than instantiating new product model on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

For Faster import, you can use Magmi : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

once you upload products through, reindex through system > Index Management....